# What is the difference between skype static and dynamic?

Tags: 12.04, skype

What is difference between skype static and dynamic? 
which package is the best for Ubuntu 12.04 on aspire one (d255e-mic issues).
Static newest version - 2.2.0.99
Dynamic and .deb - -2.2.0.35
cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- A static binary/program is one that does not have any other dependencies; it will usually run on recent Linux distributions without having to install any other libraries.
- A dynamic binary/program (much more common) depends on other libraries to run, and your package manager will usually install these automatically when you install the program.

Short answer: go for the dynamic, unless you get some error and it doesn't work, in which case you can try static.

Answer (score 0):

You need "sudo" (root) to install dynamic build skype.
You can use regular user (dedicated for skype) to extract and run static build skype.